# Multiple variables in an if statement Python

Tags: python

I want to have more than one variable in this if statement for a calculator

```
if b != "*","/","-","+"
```

I'm not sure how to make this work so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if not b in "*+-/"`, making sure that `type(b) == str`

Comment: @ZdaR Note that searching in a string is `O(n)`, and e.g. `"/-" in "*/+-"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` operand :

```
if b not in {"*","/","-","+"}
```

Note : since checking membership in `set` object has O(1) complexity if you want to do this task multiple time you better to use `set`.

But if you are dealing with a simple task you can check with `"*/-+"` too.